# Remapping keyboard shortcuts in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, firefox, switching

I recently switched from Windows to Mac.  One of the things that's really ingrained in my muscle memory is hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in a browser to go to the address bar.  On Mac browsers, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> creates a bookmark, the equivalent to move to the address bar is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

I've used the Keyboard pref pane to remap <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to the "Open Location..." command in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.  In Safari this works great.  In both Chrome and Firefox, hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> now goes to the address bar **and** creates a bookmark.  Is there any way to get this to work properly in Chrome and Firefox?

Mac OS 10.7, Chrome 13.0.782.220, Firefox 6.0.2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve this using the keyboard prefs just as you were trying. You simply need to create one more shortcut.

In Chrome you would:

- Set <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to `Open Location…`
- Set <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to `Bookmark This Page…`

By setting an explicit shortcut for `Bookmark This Page…` you get rid of the conflict an ensure there aren't two menu options with the same shortcut.

Comment: Could someone extend this answer for dummies, please? I'm not sure where this Keyboard prefs page is. Is this System Preferences > Keyboard? If so, I added Google Chrome and the shortcuts mentioned above and relaunched Chrome but the shortcut actions did not change.

Comment: I figured it out. My browser was not in English. :)

Comment: it took me a moment to find, even today under El Capitan. it's under System Preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts. adding and removing shortcuts is done using the *unlabeled* plus and minus below the shortcuts list.

Comment: It's `Bookmark This Tab...` in newer versions.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this from `System Preferences`→`Keyboard`→`Shortcuts`. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/174979/1443

Here are my current settings:

[image]

Comment: Get an app (free and OS) Called CheatSheet, and with that you can see all the shortcuts used by the app, and if you make a rule in the Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts using the exact text given in CheatSheet it will change it to what you select..

Comment: here's the link https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately none of the extensions I have work. However, there is a way to do this in the version of OSX I'm using, at least. Go to Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts, and then from the list on the left select "App Shortcuts". Click "+" to add a new app shortcut and then select Google Chrome from the list of Apps.

Now, you must assign "Bookmark This Page..." to something else first so that you can truly override command+D. I chose to select shift+command+B.

After that click "+" again, and assign "Open Location..." to command+D. Now it should work.

I can't believe how long it took me to find this answer, I guess everyone else uses Alt+L or Firefox. Thanks to Pysis for their [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/980324/672724).

Edit: This was so frustrating I made an account just to respond to this.

Comment: Damn how is such a simple thing as customising shortcuts not natively integrated in Chrome -_- Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

[ShortcutManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) (Chrome extension) allows you to:

> Customize shortcut keys; Assign any Javascript code or browser actions to any key strokes.

[Here's](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060112112609860) an article on remapping keyboard shortcuts for Firefox. You'll need [the keyconfig extension.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/functions-for-keyconfig/)

Comment: This extension is useless on OS X. Let's say I try to add a shortcut Ctrl+t to open a new tab. The extension refuses to do that, and says that shortcut is already assigned to do open a new tab. That may be the case on other platforms, but not on OS X. The whole reason I want to add this shortcut in the first place is to map the action on the same keys as on other platforms.

Comment: Another way that this extension fails is that pressing "Command" produces META+META, so "Command + 1" doesn't produce the desired result. The answer by @Samuel Mikel Bowles solves the problem.