# How to create custom Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there any way to create custom keyboard shortcuts that do whatever you want through a third-party app or just through default OS X apps, like Automator and or AppleScript?

I want to create a shortcut that will bring up the power dialogue box, as shown in the image below.

[image: Power Dialogue Box]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my 2013 MacBook Pro with Yosemite <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>eject</kbd> does fine for bringing that dialog up.

As an aside, the behavior of the power button has become a bit fiddly (annoying...) for me.

Comment: Even though I didn't get to make a custom shortcut you still helped a bit.

Comment: [control] + [power] works similarly on new Macs where the power button is in the place of the old eject button.  You'll have to hold it down a bit as it has a time delay (like [caps lock]) so you don't press it accidentally.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're on a normal Mac then the power button will bring it up. Details [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).

Further details about creating shortcuts [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18418?locale=en_US).

You can use the info in that document to create a short-cut in any app for whatever key combo you want for the Shutdown... item.

Simplified procedure:

1. Open System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab
2. From the left, click App Shortcuts.
3. Click +
4. Choose 'All Applications' as the app
5. Choose 'Shut Down...' as the command
6. Put in whatever shortcut you want.

Comment: Just a comment on the "Simplified procedure:", this does not bring up the same shutdown dialog box as shown in the OP, under OS X 10.8.x anyway.  Also Finder has to have the focus as well otherwise it doesn't trigger.

Comment: Don't use Finder, use Any.

Comment: @Tetsujin - yes, good call. Updated.

Comment: Sorry, meant all apps [was on my phone] I re-edited

Comment: in fact @user3439894 is correct, it's a different dialog, no options. Steve's answer is actually closer to what the OP wanted, in fact. I missed that earlier, sorry all.

Comment: Well, I covered that case in the initial sentence - however, many users have custom keyboards, especially desktop users.

Comment: i am unable to input anything in the Keyboard shortcut field. Is this normal? I cant seem to make this work, please help

Comment: You are my Savior. Google changes the name of the action AGAIN and I'm using your answer 3 times already. Still working