# Remapping keybinding not workin in Firefox for MacOS (mojave)

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, firefox, web-browser

Coming from Windows, I wished to change the `Open Location...` keybinding for my browsers. I was able to do it for Chrome by following the suggestions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24609/remapping-keyboard-shortcuts-in-chrome-and-firefox), but the same process does not work for Firefox.

I looked at the other answers where they [suggest](https://superuser.com/questions/1271147/change-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-quantum) an Add-on called Saka but it is really complicated for me. All I wish is to have the following Keybindings.

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>   for Open Locations...
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>   for Bookmark this Page...

I am using MacOS Mojave (10.14.5) and Firefox (67.0)

I would be grateful if someone could help me figure this out.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't have FF to test, but in general for menu replacements you must have the **exact** menu name. I suspect you're using 3 stops ... rather than an ellipsis … They may look the same, but they're not the same to the system.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Tetsujin. But as you can see in this [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mp1b667otegeq8q/Screenshot%202019-05-27%20at%202.16.58%20AM.png?dl=0), there is no `...` in bookmarks option for Firefox.

Comment: Well, you added one in your question - anyway, why not use the system shortcut replacer, it looks like a regular menu item?

Comment: @vykor - nice find. I wasn't aware Firefox was as awkward as Chrome for ignoring the standard Mac toolbox. I'll stick with Safari ;)